# Spreadsheet to mariaDB

Tags: html, templates, mariadb

We have used a spreadsheet for our client management so far.

Now we are growing and want more users to simultaneously work on the data. We don't want to introduce a CRM because we want to store the data locally and already have a pretty sophisticated script that takes the data from the rows of the spreadsheet via the clipboard and runs operations on it.

We have a Synology NAS that supports MariaDB.

I thought this should be a pretty simple database use case for a HTML website in a browser:

- Filtering for existing entries
- Manipulating existing entries by
  row
- Adding new entries

Also, it'd be great to restrict visible entries to a certain amount of rows.

Does anyone know of existing templates which support that?

Thank you!